# Download Excel of the filtered data in laravel

Tags: javascript, excel, laravel, filter

I apologize if this question has a similar problem. I am using Laravel and I'm facing issues with downloading an Excel file. I want to download an Excel file containing filtered data using the modal I created. However, the Excel file is empty, and it only contains column names.

this the Modal and Javascript

```
<div class="modal fade" id="modal_search" tabindex="-1" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
<div class="modal-dialog modal-dialog-centered modal-xl">
    <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
            <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">Filter</h5>
            <button type="button" class="btn-close" data-bs-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"></button>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
            <div class="container-fluid shadow py-3 px-5 main-f for_label">
                <div class="row p-1">
                    <div class="col-12 col-md-4 col-lg-4">
                        <label for="form" class="p-1">Location</label>
                        <select name="irlocation" id="irlocation" class="form-select for_label">
                            <option disabled selected>--Select--</option>
                            @foreach($location as $loc)
                            <option value='{{ $loc->loc_name }}'>{{ $loc->loc_name }}</option>
                            @endforeach
                        </select>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-12 col-md-4 col-lg-4">
                        <label for="form" class="p-1">Type</label>
                        <select name="irtype" id="irtype" class="form-select for_label">
                            <option disabled selected>--Select--</option>
                            @foreach($incidenttype as $incident)
                            <option value='{{ $incident->incidenttype }}'>{{ $incident->type_name }}</option>
                            @endforeach
                         </select>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-12 col-md-4 col-lg-4">
                        <label for="form" class="p-1">Project Name</label>
                        <select name="irtype" id="irtype" class="form-select for_label">
                            <option disabled selected>--Select--</option>
                            @foreach($systemapps as $system)
                            <option value='{{ $system->systemapps }}'>{{ $system->syst_xname }}</option>
                            @endforeach
                        </select>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-12 col-md-4 col-lg-4">
                    <button type="button" id="downloadBtn" class="btn btn-allcard">Download Excel</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

```
$('#downloadBtn').click(function() {
       var location = $('#irlocation').val();
       var incidentType = $('#irtype').val();
       var projectName = $('#projectName').val();

       var url = '{{ route("download.excel") }}?irlocation=' + location + '&irtype=' + incidentType + '&projectName=' + projectName;
       window.location.href = url;});
```

this the API controller

```
public function downloadExcel(Request $request)
{
    // Retrieve the filter parameters from the request
    $location = $request->input('irlocation');
    $incidentType = $request->input('irtype');
    $projectName = $request->input('projectName');

    // Query the incident reports based on the filter parameters
    $query = IncidentReports::query();

    if ($location) {
        $query->where('incident_location', $location);
    }

    if ($incidentType) {
        $query->where('incident_type', $incidentType);
    }

    if ($projectName) {
        $query->where('incident_affected', $projectName);
    }

    $incidentReports = $query->get();

    // Define the Excel export class
    $export = new class ($incidentReports) implements FromCollection, WithHeadings {
        private $incidentReports;

        public function __construct($incidentReports)
        {
            $this->incidentReports = $incidentReports;
        }

        public function collection()
        {
            return $this->incidentReports;
        }

        public function headings(): array
        {
            // Define the column headings for the Excel file
            return [
                'Incident #',
                'Title',
                'Creator',
                'Incident Type',
                'Location',
            ];
        }
    };

    // Generate the Excel file and force download
    return Excel::download($export, 'incident_reports.xlsx');
}
```

this the exports

```
    <?php

namespace App\Exports;

use App\Models\IncidentReports;
use Maatwebsite\Excel\Concerns\FromCollection;
use Maatwebsite\Excel\Concerns\WithHeadings;

class IncidentReportsExport implements FromCollection, WithHeadings
{
    protected $incidentReports;

    public function __construct($incidentReports)
    {
        $this->incidentReports = $incidentReports;
    }

    public function collection()
    {
        return $this->incidentReports;
    }

    public function headings(): array
    {
        return [
            'Incident #',
            'Title',
            'Creator',
            'Incident Type',
            'Location',
            'Action',
        ];
        
    }
}


enter code here
```